# how to make a clause in pyswip

Tags: python, prolog, swi-prolog

can any one here help me to make prolog clauses inside python using pyswip like this

database:

```
man(peter).
woman(adam).
man(jonathan).
man(paul).
woman(cloe).
father(jonathan, peter).
father(pierre, adam).
brother(pierre, paul).
father(pierre, cloe).
```

these are functions

```
child(X, Y) :- father(Y,X).
son(X, Y) :- man(X) , father(Y, X).
daughter(X, Y) :- woman(X), father(Y, X).
brother(X, Y) :- man(X), father(Z, Y), father(Z, X).
sister(X, Y) :- woman(X), father(Z, Y), father(Z, X).
```

how can i define these prolog functions inside python through pyswip

Comment: It turns out you can do `prolog.assertz("man(peter)")` to assert the facts, _and_ you can do `prolog.assertz("child(X,Y) :- father(Y,X)")` to add the rules.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have time to make a detailed answer right now, I'll update it latter but here's a simple example of an interface in python I had done to a prolog program that played reversi.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from pyswip import Prolog, Functor, Variable, Query

prolog = Prolog()
prolog.consult('./reversi_game.pl')
prolog.consult('./alphabeta.pl')

start_board = Functor("startBoard", 1)
b = Variable()
start_board_query = Query(start_board(b))
start_board_query.nextSolution()
print()
print_board(list(b.get_value())) # an 8*8 grid filled with 0 except at the 4 center squares that have x's and o's
start_board_query.closeQuery()

set_to_x = Functor("setToX", 1)
xp = Variable()
set_player_query = Query(set_to_x(xp))
set_player_query.nextSolution()
x_player = xp.get_value()
print()
print(x_player) # 'x'
set_player_query.closeQuery()
```

So what it is going on here? To define the predicate interface you create a Functor, giving it a string which is the name of the predicate in Prolog and its  arity, you create as many variables as you need and pass them to your Functor creating a Query from it.

You can then proceed calling `nextSolution()` on the Query object for as long as you want depending on how many solutions you need, if I remember correctly  the result will be None when it fails and it stops giving any solutions. Then use the `get_value()` function to extract the values of the variables of your predicate.

You can also check this out:
https://github.com/yuce/pyswip/tree/master/examples

Hope it helps.

EDITED:

I know this "promised a bit more detailed answer" is a bit late now, but anyways.

Comment: Only now that I edited my answer almost an year after, I realised you wanted to create clauses in Prolog from Python, and not working with existing predicates and creating an interface to your Prolog program. For creating clauses like you want to examples provided in the link in my answer are very explanatory.